# How do I change an external JAR for multiple Eclipse projects at once?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

There are hundreds of Java projects in my Eclipse workspace. All of these projects depend on an external JAR. When I made those projects, I never bothered to add a Javadoc location to this external JAR, but now I regret not doing that.

Is there a way to add Javadoc for this particular external JAR for multiple projects at once? This way I don't have to open properties and add the Javadoc location for each project.

Thanks

Comment: You can add that jar to a user library, and include that library for all projects.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know a way, but can tell a *hack*:

Open some of your `.classpath` files (in the root of each project). They probably all contain a `<classpathentry>` related to your JAR. Add the Javadoc location to one and check the change in the `<classpathentry>`; it will be something like:

```
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:file:/path/to/javadoc.jar!/"/>
    </attributes>
```

Mass replace the plain `<classpathentry>` with the enhanced one; DON'T FORGET TO BACK THINGS UP BEFORE DOING THIS :)